# addClass/removeClass by Class Name(not ID)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to know how to removeClass by Class Name using jquery. I know how to do it by ID. I'm trying this:

```
var ButtonNumber = document.querySelectorAll(".ButtonStyleClicked");

for (var i = 0; i < ButtonNumber.length; i++) {
     var ClassName = ButtonNumber[i];
     $('.' + ClassName).removeClass('ButtonStyleClicked');

    }
```

Removing a class by ID works like this:

```
var ID = document.getElementById(Whatever);

$('#' + ID).removeClass('ButtonStyleClicked');
```

Solved the problem:

The querySelectorAll was shooting back an DIV element. So I stuck just the result into the remove class and that worked:

```
var ButtonNumber = document.querySelectorAll(".ButtonStyleClicked");

for (var i = 0; i < ButtonNumber.length; i++) {
     var ClassName = ButtonNumber[i];
     $(ClassName).removeClass('ButtonStyleClicked');

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to find elements with the `ButtonStyleClicked` class to remove the class from?

```
$('.ButtonStyleClicked').removeClass('ButtonStyleClicked');
```

(If you need to store the class name in a variable:)

```
var className = 'ButtonStyleClicked';
$('.' + className).removeClass(className);
```

Comment: I figured out the problem and updated my question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can use whatever the selector is. Let's say

```
var className = "myClass";
$("."+className).removeClass(className);
```

You can use as many selector items and combinations as needed. For example; in case you just want to remove certain class from the `<p>` tags that are children of a `<div>` tag with an id of "myDiv", it would be something like:

```
$("div#myDiv p."+className).removeClass(className);
```